# Some point features in feature class not displaying in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, sql-server

I am trying to display a point feature class, but a few features from the same data set are not displayed.

Originally I have heaps of point features in a point feature class, which are well displayed in my map extent (ArcGIS 10.2 / ArcGIS 10.3.1).

Incremental updates are provided by the supplier which are handled and updated (added/deleted) to the main feature class through SQL.

main feature class

[image]

When imported to ArcMap 10.2

[image]

In ArcMap using SQL table I run a query and 4 points are returned (2 previous and 2 updated) but when exported only 2 records (previous) are displayed.
[image]
[image]

I am struggling to find out what is wrong with the updated records, so are not displayed.

Comment: What are the results of Check Geometry? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000034000000. Have the attributes of this dataset been edited by MS Access or Excel?

Comment: I performed the geometry check and found no error. No attributes edited in any application.